# libgdx-using more than one class

Tags: libgdx

Hi i am very new to programming and in this community,so im recently studying on how to develop games with libgdx and all the tutorials only have one class and do all the things in that class,but is it possible to use more than one class?(ex:individual class for player, mobs , etc) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer; **Yes**, it is possible to use more than one class when doing **libGDX** development.

But don't worry about it, asking if *X* is possible isn't always that useful, I think you'll have more luck with asking questions on this site if you instead try 
to implement something and when you hit a problem you ask specifically about that.

Just asking if multiple classes is possible doesn't necessarily give you a relevant answer as the question doesn't constrain the context enough and is also opinion based (as to where and how multiple classes should be used in **libGDX**).

If you want to look at a game that has a more complex implementation, have a look at [Super Jumper](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper).